# insert into table using trigger give

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

following trigger was working fine, but nows after change in table and schema gives error:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `invite`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `invite` AFTER INSERT ON `Invite_page`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    Insert into userpost(userid,url,title,preview,sentiment,time) values(NEW.userid,NEW.url,NEW.title,NEW.preview,NEW.sentiment,NEW.time);

Insert into urlcontent(url,title,preview,sentiment,time) values(NEW.url,NEW.title,NEW.preview,NEW.sentiment,NEW.time);
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Error is:

`Error: Unknown column 'userid' in 'NEW'`

Table contains columns correctly:

PHP code:

```
<?php       

        $url=$_POST['url'];
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $title=$_POST['title'];
        $preview=$_POST['preview'];
        $sentiment=$_POST['sent'];

        $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'karim');
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            return;
        }

        $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            //echo $datel
        $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO invite_page(`userid`, `url`, `title`, `preview` ,`sentiment`,`time`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$url."','".$title."','".$preview."','".$sentiment."','".$date."')";

        //$insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO userpost(`url`, `title`, `preview` ,`sentiment`,`time`) VALUES ('".$url."','".$title."','".$preview."','".$sentiment."')";       

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }


        echo "Record added successful ..";

?>
```

where is the issue I could not find

Comment: The PHP code you're showing us is ridiculously open to SQL Injection.  Please use proper prepared statements, or be hacked by completely automated tools.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger and everything is correct.

Error was due to some another trigger existing in the same schema. I was not aware about.

Apologize for inconvenience.